# How to tar/untar the output on the fly

Tags: bash, tar, stdout

What is the idiomatic way to do the following

- tar to stdout
- read this tar output from stdout and extract to some other folder.

My solution is
  `tar --to-stdout .. | tar -C somefolder -xvf -`

But may be there is more idiomatic way to do it.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**The same *`-f -`* option** works for tarring as well.

```
tar -cf - something | tar -C somefolder -xvf -
```

GNU tar uses stdio by default:

```
tar -c something | tar -C somefolder -xv
```

---

rsync is also popular.

```
rsync -av something/ somefolder/
```

Answer (score 11):

Just adding another use-case here. I had a large directory structure on a system nearly out of disk space and wanted to end up with a tar.gz file of the directory structure on another machine with lots of space.

`tar -czf - big-dir | ssh user@host 'cat > /path/to/big-dir.tar.gz'`

This saves on network overhead and means you don't have to tar on the other side in case you'd wanted to use rsync for the transfer instead.

Comment: Netcat is perfect for this. (Cat from one host to another host).

Comment: @Hennes: With its lack of authentication, integrity checking, data encryption, as well as having to manually start it on _both_ sides for each individual transfer (i.e. 2× the work), it sounds a bit less than perfect

Comment: Most of the time I gzip it before dumping it over the network. Any integretiy failures are likely to show up as decompression errors (though I never got any when I used it).  As to starting two programs: Aye, true.

Comment: It may be more work, but for sending a large compressed archive over a link during a time-sensitive operation between machines in a secured local network or over a VPN, piping through nc will be significantly faster than SSH (over a 1Gb network, often by a factor of 2). Send over an md5 sum of the archive for integrity checking.

Comment: whats the netcat command?

Comment: Why not use tar's built-in remote access functionality?

Comment: @ReeseWang how about an example command? When I check `man tar` and search for "remote" there are no matches. Personally I didn't know tar had remote capabilities.

Comment: @quickshiftin `tar --zstd -cf 192.168.1.2:/home/user/backup.tar.zstd --rsh-command=/usr/bin/ssh ./` see [this](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html) man page.

Comment: Ah, looks like it's a bit different on a Mac. Rang up the man page on a Linux box today and I see the remote options. Your point is well taken, may answer is ignorance lol.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to post a comment about using netcat.

On the receiving end run:
`netcat -l 5555 > /path/to/dest.tar.gz` or `netcat -l 5555 | tar -C /path/to/expanded/tar -xz`

On the sending side run:
`tar -C /path/to/source -cz files | netcat <target IP/hostname> 5555`

If you are on a fast network, don't bother compressing and decompressing the tar. Used some variant of this over the years for all kinds of recovery.

Comment: Robert, thank you for this addition. I think it's fine per se as an answer, so it's even better - I hope you'll pretty soon will have reputation for comments as well though )